# Click Event of Dynamically generated Anchor Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an anchor on Lable Text.I am creating anchor with runat="server" dynamically on click of a button, It gets created as expected. I want to use its click event but it does not fire.

**My code :**

```
lblEmail.Text = email + " <a href='#' runat='server' class='crossicon' onclick='removebtn_Click'></a> ";

protected void removebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

How Can I create event for this button?I don't want to use JS, as in that case I will have to use a hidden field for new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, controls use __doPostBack to do the postback to the server. __doPostBack takes the UniqueID of the control (or in HTML, the name property of the HTML element). The second parameter is the name of the command to fire.

```
<a href='#' runat='server' class='crossicon' href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="__doPostBack('someuniqueid', '');></a>
```

System.Web.UI.Page already implements the IPostBackEventHandler interface by default, so you don't need to implement it on every page - it's already there.

You can override the RaisePostBackEvent method on the page like this:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the RaisePostBack event 
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == SomeControl)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: you need to write your code to RaisePostBackEvent in place of removebtn_Click.

Answer (score 1):

Adding markup/text to the label in that way wouldn't add the linkbutton or register the event to the control tree at the server. For that behavior of dynamically adding controls along with the server events to be achieved, you need to register the controls and events (as shown below)

**aspx:**

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlEmail">
     <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblEmail"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

**aspx.cs:**
    In whichever event, you want to set the label text (along with the link)

```
lblEmail.Text = email;
LinkButton lnkbtnEmail = new LinkButton();
lnkbtn.Click += lnkbtn_Click;
lnkbtn.Text = "Dynamic Link";
pnlEmail.Controls.Add(lnkbtnEmail);
```

And the Handler would be

```
void lnkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // code for your dynamically generated link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it is created dynamically. Where is ID of that control. You have to Create Server side control and add it into some placeholder/panel e.t.c